# image buttons asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, imagebutton

Hi all im trying to do is pass a value to the controller using an image instead of a button. 
ive got it working using the button with.

```
<input type="submit" name="Vote" value="1" />
```

This works but when im try using a button type it fails saying that im sending a null parameter.

```
<input type="image" src="imagepath" value="1" alt="1" name="Vote" />
```

If anyone can help it would be a great thanks.

Comment: You can't set a value on an input type='image' element. It will always send the coordinates of the cursor as the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="image" src="imagepath" value="1" alt="1" name="Vote" onclick="submit" />
```

But I think you'll lose submitting by hitting the enter key.

input image "sometimes"(?) just send the x and y coordinates of the image...

`Input type="image"` is anyway something to avoid for submit buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Ajax ?

```
@Ajax.RawActionLink("Text", "Action", "Controller", null, ajaxOptions, new { @class = "button green small" })
```